# Measure DNS-Lookup time with java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I need to measure DNS Lookup time out of a java application. My idea is to measure the execution-time of InetAddress.getByName("myName"). What I'm not sure about is if this call is cached by operating-system. Can anybody tell me if so?

Is there maybe a better way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the Operating System but **Java has its own DNS cache** which are configurable via system properties. Please checkout [this link](http://java-monitor.com/forum/showthread.php?t=181) for more details.

EDIT:

Your use case warrants [disable DNS caching](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0445.html).

Answer (score 3):

Regarding caching, the javadoc of [InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) says that:

```
The InetAddress class has a cache to store successful as well as unsuccessful host name resolutions.
```

So whatever about the OS, Java caches the results.

Read on, and you can see JVM args you can specify to modify the default caching behaviour.